# Cannot reference coffee after installing CoffeeScript on Mac OS X 10.8.3

Tags: macos, coffeescript, rvm

When I enter `coffee --help` in my home folder, I get the response

```
-bash: coffee: command not found
```

Here are the steps that I have taken to try and get this working:

I have successfully installed node and npm.

```
$ node -v
v0.10.5
npm -v
1.2.18
```

I then installed coffee-script using the command:

```
npm install -g coffee-script
```

I am therefore able to see the coffee program file in `$HOME/.rvm/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin`. I decided to place a path to coffee in ~/.bashrc and it now contains the following:

```
source ~/git-completion.bash
# Show branch in status line
PS1='[W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"'
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$HOME/.rvm/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin
```

I suspect that I have probably chosen the wrong place for my path. I am not able to locate the file that contains my current environment variable path

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/francoisvdhoven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-    p392@railstutorial2ndEd/bin:/Users/francoisvdhoven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/Users/francoisvdhoven/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/Users/francoisvdhoven/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: How'd you install node and npm? Having stuff in `~/.rvm` is kind of odd.

Comment: Hi Jim, I installed node using homebrew

Comment: I eventually solved this problem by uninstalling Node Package Manager and Node.js. I then carefully followed the instructions in [link](http://gist.github.com/Frobitz/3257794). After installing Homebrew, the command "brew doctor" is a tremendous help to identify various kinds of errors that could cause problems along the way.

I hope this helps someone...